# An unbounded limit function for a sequence of bounded continuous functions.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Let ${f_n}$ be a sequence of bounded continuous functions defined on $\mathbb R$, and suppose that $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly on every finite interval $[a,b]$. Is it necessarily true that $f$ is bounded?

For this question, I can easily prove that $f$ is bounded on every finite interval $[a,b]$, but I cannot prove it is bounded on $\mathbb R$. And my professor said that this statement is not true, i.e. $f$ is not necessarily bounded on $\mathbb R$. But I'm having difficulty coming up with a counterexample. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $f=$ any continuous unbounded function.

Denote by $f_n(x)$ any continuous function such that $f_n(x)=f(x)$ if $x \in [-n,n] $, and $f_n(x)=0$ if $x \in (-\infty,-n-1) \cup (n+1,+\infty)$. It is easy to see that such a function exists, and is bounded (since it is continuous and has a compact support).

Now, using the fact that every interval $[a,b]$ is contained in a interval $[-N,N]$, you can check easily that $(f_n)$ converges to $f$ uniformly on every $[a,b]$ (actually, $f_{n|[a,b]}$ is constant equal to $f_{|[a,b]}$ for $n$ sufficiently large).

Comment: Do you mean that $f_n = 0$ if $x \in (-\infty, -n) \cup (n, \infty)$?

Comment: No, because this would not give a continuous function. Define $f_n$ equal to $f$ on $[-n,n]$, and equal to zero on $(-\infty,-n-1) \cup (n+1,+\infty)$, and complete it as you want and the intervals $[-n-1,n)$ and $(n,n+1]$ to get a continuous function.

Comment: I see what you mean! I was wondering how $f_n$ can be continuous if $f$ is not equal to $0$ at n. Thank you very much!

Comment: @NianliPeng You are welcome !